# Caldera form, civi case and custom fields integration

Tags: custom-fields, civicase, caldera-forms

I've set up a caldera form which collects information and creates a Civicase.

I've managed to set up the form which is collecting information as a particular case type called 'Get involved'.

I've created a couple of custom fields to collect check box information:

'Governing_council_check' and 'Standing Committee'.

I've connected the custom fields to the form questions in the Custom Fields section of the form processors section.

When I come to export the case however, from my case dashboard, the fields are returned blank regardless of how the form was filled out.

I'm not sure what to try and would appreciate any advice or areas to check.

Here are the custom fields in caldera forms.
[image: Image of custom fields in form]

Here are the custom fields in civi custom data
[image: Image of civi custom fields]

And here is the case export returning those fields as blank/unanswered
[image]

Comment: If you proceed to then click the download button, does it include the fields? There are some known issues with the preview screen.

Comment: Before you put too much effort into this, are you aware Caldera forms is being retired in favour of the as-yet-unreleased integration with Ninja?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help. There was an error with the data types which meant they weren't mapping properly - namely that 'checkbox' in form maps to 'drop down select' in civi if you want to allow more than one option selected.